# Configuration of texmaker with portable miktex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, miktex, texmaker

I have downloaded the portable miktex and I have installed texmaker on my computer. 
The following screenshot presents by configuration:

[image]

Apparently I am missing something because the following errors appear when I am trying to compile. Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: The texmaker console mentions a log file that "hopefully contains the information to get miktex going again" - what is the content of this log file?

Comment: @samcarter Here is the error:

`2019-02-28 17:19:14,949+0100 FATAL pdflatex - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
2019-02-28 17:19:14,949+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2019-02-28 17:19:14,949+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\config.cpp
2019-02-28 17:19:14,949+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 970`

Comment: Maybe related to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/82